# concat image file not able to create

Tags: java

I try to join two images. But not able to create it.
I am not able to understand what is the problem in the below code.
It is not able to create the concat.jpg file.

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(mainFile);
BufferedImage image1 = ImageIO.read(fileToMerge);
int width = Math.max(image.getWidth() , image1.getWidth());
int height = Math.max(image.getHeight() , image1.getHeight());
log.info("width {}", width);
log.info("height {}", height);
BufferedImage concatImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D graphics2D = concatImage.createGraphics();
graphics2D.drawImage(image, 0, image.getHeight(), null);
graphics2D.drawImage(image1, 0 , image1.getHeight(), null);
ImageIO.write(concatImage, "jpg", new File(Constants.LOCAL_FOLDER + "/concat.jpg"));
```

Comment: What would concatenate two image mean? What does "not able to create it" mean? An exception? An unexpected result?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but images have some header info and you must ignore while "merging". More, i don't see anything to transform the Graphic into a compressed image like "jpg", jpg it's a standard, not only a suffix (that's mean how the colors are memorized, just to say an easy one). I think you miss at least 2 logical steps

Answer (score 0):

You want the height of `concatImage` to be the combined height of `image` and `image1`.
You want to draw `image` at coordinates (0,0) and you want to draw `image1` at x = 0 and y = *height of `image`*
Try the following.

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(mainFile);
BufferedImage image1 = ImageIO.read(fileToMerge);
int width = Math.max(image.getWidth() , image1.getWidth());
int height = image.getHeight() + image1.getHeight();
log.info("width {}", width);
log.info("height {}", height);
BufferedImage concatImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D graphics2D = concatImage.createGraphics();
graphics2D.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
graphics2D.drawImage(image1, 0, image.getHeight(), null);
ImageIO.write(concatImage, "jpg", new File(Constants.LOCAL_FOLDER + "/concat.jpg"));
```

Note that you should call `graphics2D.dispose()` when you no longer need to use it.

Comment: I tried it but it is not working. I try to save the individual image which I am taking as input, it is able to save those images.  ```ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File(Constants.LOCAL_FOLDER + "/DONE.jpg"));```  it is able to create the DONE.jpg file. But not the concatImage. Is there any other reason because no error is showing.

Comment: @SwarnimKumar if you want me to debug your code then [edit] your question and post a [mcve]